# What's the correct syntax for returning a single value using PDO and mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to switch my sql to PDO but I'm having trouble getting even this simple query to return a value.  Surely it can't be this difficult.  I've done the same query the old fashioned way and it works perfectly as expected.  The PDO version returns nothing.  What's the trick here?

This first version returns the value I expect.

```
  $customfieldid = 676;
  $entityid = 9784549;
  $entitytype = 'familyoverview';

  $sql = "select value
                  from customfieldvalues
                 where customfieldid = ".$customfieldid."
                   and entityid = ".$entityid."
                   and entitytype = '".$entitytype."'";

  $result = mysql_query($sql);

  if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $mysqlvalue = $row["value"];
    echo "<br>mysql value: ".$mysqlvalue;
  }
```

This PDO version returns nothing.

```
  $sql = "select value
                  from customfieldvalues
                 where customfieldid = :customfieldid
                   and entityid = :entityid
                   and entitytype = :entitytype";

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  //$stmt->bindValue(':customfieldid', $customfieldid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  //$stmt->bindValue(':entityid', $entityid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  //$stmt->bindValue(':entitytype', $entitytype, PDO::PARAM_STR);

  $stmt->bindValue(':customfieldid', 676, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindValue(':entityid', 9784549, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindValue(':entitytype', 'familyoverview', PDO::PARAM_STR);

  $pdovalue = $stmt->fetchColumn();
  echo "<br>pdo value: ".$pdovalue;
```

I've confirmed that I have a pdo database connection.  I've tried using the third parameter and omitting the third parameter in the bindValue calls.  I've also tried hardcoding the values in the bindValue calls vs passing them in but none of that makes any difference.

Comment: @duskwuff is correct, you need a call to $stmt->execute(). But I wanted to offer a comment that bindValue() is unnecessary, you can simply pass the params as an array to `$stmt->execute()`. I don't know why so many people learning PDO overlook this. See example #2 on this page: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: @BillKarwin …but only if you're using positional parameters, and if all of those parameters can accept strings.

Comment: No, you can pass an associative array for named parameters. Look at the example in the page I linked to. And it doesn't matter what types. The MySQL PDO driver always passes parameters as strings anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Bill.  Not sure I like that due to readability, but it may be just a matter of getting used to it.  I'll consider it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PDO code is missing a call to `$stmt->execute()`, so the query is never sent to the MySQL server and executed. Without executing the query, there can't be any results.

Comment: Thank you!  My assumption was that $stmt->fetchColumn() was in place of the execute() call.  Didn't realize I needed both.

Comment: `PDOStatement->fetchColumn()` is more comparable to `mysql_fetch_array()`. `mysql_query()` is essentially a combination of `PDO->prepare()`, `PDOStatement->bindValue()`, and `PDOStatement->execute()`.